# Merge into list groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a such dataframe

```
    id  sid frame   type    
    1   10  15      person
    2   11  45      person  
    2   11  45      animal  
    3   13  75      person  
    4   14  45      person
```

my goal is to transform this dataframe in this.

```
    id  sid frame   type    
    1   10  15      person
    2   11  45      [person, animal]    
    3   13  75      person  
    4   14  45      person
```

Im looking a for a way to merge `type` column in a row with the same `id, sid, frame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `list` with condition:

```
df = (df.groupby(['id','sid','frame'])['type']
       .apply(lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.values[0])
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  sid  frame              type
0   1   10     15            person
1   2   11     45  [person, animal]
2   3   13     75            person
3   4   14     45            person
```

If all values should be `list`s:

```
df = (df.groupby(['id','sid','frame'])['type']
       .apply(list)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  sid  frame              type
0   1   10     15          [person]
1   2   11     45  [person, animal]
2   3   13     75          [person]
3   4   14     45          [person]
```

Comment: Thx, this is what I'm looking for